# USB ImageWriter not in Software Center

Tags: software-installation, usb

Imagewriter appears to be missing from newer Ubuntu release repositories.
Is there a problem here?  How can I get ImageWriter in Ubuntu 13.04?

Answer (score 2):

Writing disk images is an available feature in `gnome-disk-utility`.

Comment: This is a very late answer ...

Comment: It is a currently correct answer. I took the time out of my day to answer as soon as I saw the question.

Comment: It is in fact a currently correct answer.

Comment: @SorenA Answering old questions is one of the best things anyone can do on Stack Exchange sites. Please do not mislead users to think that old questions do not matter or should not be given attention.

Answer (score 1):

[I would advise installing the 12.10 version](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/usb-imagewriter/).

Long answer:

From [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer):

> **Image Writer for Windows**
>
> This tool is used for writing images to USB sticks or SD/CF cards on Windows.
>
> This program was initially written to fill a need for Ubuntu Jaunty (9.04) Netbook Remix. Recently, it has grown in popularity for other project developers, namely Arm development projects (Android, Ubuntu on Arm, etc). Anyone is free to branch and modify this program. Patches are always welcome.
>
> This project is currently being migrated to Sourceforge. Please be patient.
>
> [Downloads are now on Sourceforge only](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/).

From the readme:

```
===================
Build Instructions:
===================
Requirements:
1. MinGW (20120426 from http://mingw.org)
2. Qt for Windows SDK (currently using 4.8.4 mingw from http://qt-project.org)

Short Version:
1. Install the Qt Full SDK
2. Run compile.bat -OR- run qmake and then make in the src folder.
3. Compile.bat may be edited to change installation paths of MinGW and QT
```

It will be complicated to install.